# Incrementar um número em uma consulta SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho a consulta que me retorna os resultados. Eu gostaria de adicionar um número incremental de forma a mostrar os registros do 1 até o final, como se fosse uma nova coluna.

```
select *, sum(valor) as ValorSoma, count(pedido) as QtdPedido from tb_vendas
where idvendas > 0
and data_venda between '05/10/2015' and '11/04/2016'
and vendedor =’’
group by cliente 
order by QtdPedido desc
```

Answer (score 4):

É só usar o comando `ROW_NUMBER()`. No seu caso adicione o seguinte `SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY QtdPedido desc), ...`

Fonte:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186734(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: Nota: Eu vi que tinha uma pergunta idêntica só que para outro banco(Postgre), mas mesmo a resposta sendo a mesma assumi que seria correto não marcar esta pergunta como duplicada e responder.

Answer (score -1):

Galera, depois de muito procurar e não encontrar o que precisava, a melhor solução para mim foi a seguinte:

```
-- declarar uma variavel
DECLARE @counter int
-- Definir um numero inicial para o contador
SET @counter = (SELECT MAX(id)+1 AS LAST_EMP FROM [schema].[DBO].[table])

-- somar as linhas com o valor definido
SELECT   (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY r.id DESC) + @counter) ROW
from table r
group by r.id
```